# possible to only specify location of window and not size?

Tags: python, tkinter

Every example I see **only** shows things like `root.geometry("300x300+300+300")` and I've searched for a bit now but haven't found a way to only specify the last 2 items, `"+300+300"`, can't think of a way around it either as I am inexperienced with tkinter.

Any solution is welcome, as long as I don't have to rewrite tons of code... it's a biggin.

EDIT:

I tried doing `root.geometry("+300+300")` and I get this:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible to use `root.geometry('+300+300')`.  Have you ever tried it?

Comment: Have you simply tried to do what you're asking about?

Comment: I did try that, didn't seem to work... I edited the post with the error I received.

Comment: I do not believe it's possible for that line of code to generate that error. Please provide a complete [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I've figured it out, I was using a 3rd party tkinter library called "customtkinter" it throws the error mentioned in original post on CTkToplevel, just an issue that hasen't been resolved yet, tried on an actual tkinter toplevel and it worked without issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).